# Open txt file and translate to pig latin

Tags: file, python-3.x, translate

I'm new to python 3 and I'm trying to figure out how I can open a txt file that contains a bunch of words, and translate them into pig latin. There was a couple links I found on this site explaining how to input words and translate them to pig latin, but I can't figure out how to translate words that are in a txt file.

Comment: OK guy, firstly you open the txt file as following:[link](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python). After that, you take each words and translate as [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22764946/translating-pig-latin-into-english-using-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [reading and writing files in Python](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and [`nltk`](http://www.nltk.org/).